# Count the number of correct answers in database

Tags: php, loops, oop

I am trying to count the correct answers in the database. I have the following lines of code:

```
$getresult = $quizAns->getAnswersByUser($_POST['user_id']); 

if($getresult){

$count = count($getresult);

for ($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++) {

      $match = $quiz->matchAnswer($getresult[$x]->question_id, $getresult[$x]->ans_id);

  }

}

$counts = count($match);
```

In the `$getresult` I am getting numbers of answers submitted by a user which should have to be 4 always like this:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 220
            [user_id] => 84
            [question_id] => 43
            [answer_id] => 31
        )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 219
        [user_id] => 84
        [question_id] => 48
        [answer_id] => 53
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 218
        [user_id] => 84
        [question_id] => 49
        [answer_id] => 56
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 217
        [user_id] => 84
        [question_id] => 50
        [answer_id] => 62
    )

)
```

I want to loop through every index and count the number of matched answer. But, if I try to debug `$counts` I am getting 1 only. I expect to have 4 or 3 but not one only. Follwing code is for the function match answer:

```
public function matchAnswer($question_id, $ans_id){

    $args = array(

            'where' => array(

            'id'    => $question_id,
            'ans_id' => $ans_id

        )

    );

    return $this->select($args);

}
```

And here is the function for `getAnswersByUser`:

```
public function getAnswersByUser($id, $is_die = false){

    $args = array(

        'where' => array(

            'user_id' => $id

            )


        );

        return $this->select($args);

}
```

Comment: What is the code for `getAnswersByUser`?

Comment: @NigelRen I have added function in my question.

Comment: you are not incrementing `counts` variable. it should be within the loop.

Comment: Check the results of `$this->select($args)`, make sure this is returning the list your expecting.

Comment: convert $match[] = $quiz->matchAnswer($getresult[$x]->question_id, $getresult[$x]->ans_id);

Comment: @M.Hemant doing that will output 5 as a number of the correct answer, however, there is only 4 question.

Comment: @Ash-b can you show me how can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this with

```
$getresult = $quizAns->getAnswersByUser($_POST['user_id']); 

if($getresult){

$count = count($getresult);

for ($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++) {

  $match = $quiz->matchAnswer($getresult[$x]->question_id,$getresult[$x]->ans_id);

}

}

$counts = count($match);
```

with

```
$getresult = $quizAns->getAnswersByUser($_POST['user_id']); 
$counts = 0;
if($getresult){
    $count = count($getresult);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
        $match = $quiz->matchAnswer($getresult[$x]->question_id, $getresult[$x]->ans_id);
        if($match){
           $counts += 1;
        }
    }
}
    $counts = count($match);
}
```

Comment: the first options returns 0 and the second returns 5 both are not correct.

Comment: I want to increase the value of count if the answer is correct.

Comment: can you check the output of `$this->select($args)`

Comment: if I check the output ut gives query that should be executed in the database. The output is `SELECT  *  FROM quiz WHERE id = :id AND ans_id = :ans_id ORDER BY quiz.id DESC`

Comment: If I run the query by going to database it gives me the correct answer.

Comment: Thank for your effort but, it is still giving me 1 which is not correct. I think the loop is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190143/discussion-between-ash-b-and-alisha).